# Need to check where reposync is saving the .rpm files

Tags: yum, repository

I am working in a `yum` repository that is for RHEL6 (This is our copy of the RHEL6 `yum` repo). I need to do `reposync` so that this server can get the latest version of all the packages. I need to know in which all the RPM packages are getting saved.

Like is there any file that can let me know whenever I am running `reposync` where the `.rpm` files are saved?

In short, I want to know, how can I know the name and location of all repositories that my server is hosting. And where the repo files are getting saved.

I have tried looking for the solution on StackOverflow and other sites. I am getting information on how to create a new repo but I couldn't find the answer that I want.

Comment: There's … there's no new RHEL6 packages. Maintenance support of RHEL 6 ended November 2020. There's, if anything, a "Extended Life Cycle Support Add-On" subscription (probably: big money) which promises "select and urgent security patches for a few packages" on the ELS inclusion list, and that only exists within RedHat Enterprise subscriptions offering exactly the technical support you need, I guess?

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for the revert I was able to find that my server was not registered with Extended Life Cycle Support Add-On license that is why I was not able to update it's kernel version from local repo. But my main concern was regarding my repo server which is Registered with Extended Life Cycle Support Add-On license. And I want to know the details of all the repository that it is hosting

Comment: so ask IBM/Redhat? you're paying these guys!

Comment: Have you looked at the `reposync` man page? It explicitly answers this question. Look in particular at the `EXAMPLES` section as well as the docs for the `--download_path` option.